# Ejb 3 what is the type of bean, stateless or statefull

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.2

I am trying to migrate ejb 2.1 to ejb 3.2. In ejb 2.1 EJBMetaData object has isStateless() function. So i can check the type of bean(stateless or stateful) with ejb home interface's metadata object.

In ejb 3 we don't have EJBHome and EJBMEtaData object. After lookup, ejb container provide us remote object's Proxy instance. I need to know, how can i check the type of bean from remote object.

Thank you...

Comment: Why do you need to know if it's stateless or stateful? What's the actual problem?

Comment: Because my server caches all created beans different contexts according to bean type.

Comment: Is that something you know you want to have in an EJB3 environment? Why would you cache the beans yourself?